# how to create a nested structure in c like in the body of the query?

Tags: c, struct, nested

//Contains the solution taking all answers to consideration.

```
typedef struct{
        struct address{
                int row0[10], row1[5];
        } addr;
        int * map[2];
}registers;

registers new_reg() {
    registers r = { { {0}, {0} }, {r.addr.row0, r.addr.row1} };
    return r;
}
int main() {
    registers reg = new_reg();
    reg.map[0][0] = 5;
    printf("%d\n", reg.map[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

//Contains the solution taking all answers to consideration.

Comment: Do you want to declare a new structure type or define a local object?

Comment: i want to have a nested structure. in one structure there will be arrays of different length. and in another structure, I want a array of pointers pointing to those arrays

Comment: You did not answer my question. Do you want to define objects of this type later at other locations in your code?

Comment: Yes, I do want to define objects of this type at other locations.

Comment: You mean a `union { struct { int row0[10], row1[5]; } addr; int i[15] }` so that `r.addr.row0[1] <-> r.i[1]`?

Comment: yes, you are correct. @Neil

Comment: @Neil i wud like to see ur solution with union too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct reg {
    struct address {
        int row0[10];
        int row1[5];
    } addr;
    int *i[2];
};

int main(void) {
    struct reg r;
    r.i[0] = r.addr.row0;
    r.i[1] = r.addr.row1;
    r.i[0][0] = 1;
    printf("%d\n", r.i[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

You can alternatively create an initialization function:

```
void reg_init (struct reg *pr) {
    pr->i[0] = pr->addr.row0;
    pr->i[1] = pr->addr.row1;
}
```

and then call `reg_init (& r)` every time after you define a new object of type `struct reg`. Then your new main function would be:

```
int main(void) {
    struct reg r;
    reg_init (& r);
    r.i[0][0] = 1;
    printf("%d\n", r.i[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: If you want to have a dynamic number of rows, you could declare

```
struct reg {
    struct address {
        int row[N][MAX_NUMBER];
    } addr;
    int *i[N];
};
```

and have a loop in the init function.

Comment: I have seen this. but my problem is r.i[0] = r.addr.row0; I want r.i = {r.addr.row0,r.addr.row1}
also can I not initialize the structure within instead of having an extra function for init.

Comment: I provided an alternative approach with an init function in my answer.

Comment: even if i need a separate function to init i would also like to use a loop. for example r.i[0] to r.i[x] to init r.addr.row0 to r.addr.rowX

Comment: thank you, I wud upvote if it had reputation

Answer (score 0):

"something similar" is not particularly descriptive, and you almost certainly do *not* want to do this, but you *can* do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct reg{
        struct address{
                int row0[10], row1[5];
        } addr;
        int * i[2];
};

int
main(void)
{
        struct reg r = { { {0}, {0} }, {r.addr.row0, r.addr.row1} };
        r.i[0][0] = 1;
        printf("%d\n", r.i[0][0]);
        return 0;
}
```

Some compilers even allow you to write:

```
struct reg r = { .i = {r.addr.row0, r.addr.row1} };
```

Comment: thank you, I wud upvote if it had reputation

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can specify a `union` that aliases `r.addr.row0[0]` with `r.i[0]` -- they are actually the same address in memory, just called by a different name.

```
#include <stdio.h>

union reg {
    struct {
        int row0[10], row1[5];
    } addr;
    int i[15];
};

int main(void) {
    union reg r;
    r.i[0] = 1;
    r.i[10] = 42;
    printf("%d -- %d\n", r.i[0], r.addr.row0[0]);
    printf("%d -- %d\n", r.i[10], r.addr.row1[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs,

```
1 -- 1
42 -- 42
```

It does this by [overlaying the elements of the `union`](http://www.c-faq.com/struct/union.html), instead of the `struct` which assigns unique addresses to all it's members.

Comment: Thank you Neil. Is it possible to do, i[0][0] <-> row0[0] instead using union?

Comment: You mean, `i[2][10]`? Yes, but of course that changes the size, (`sizeof int[15] -> sizeof int[20]`.) `union` always occupies the largest space of it's members.

Comment: what i mean is the variable i be like an address holder. for example int * i[2] and still have the same size? i[1] is will be 10 and i[2] will be 5. that way i[1] <-> row0

Comment: That is not possible because the compiler calculates the offsets beforehand and puts them into the code at compile-time, not run-time. With C, you can only specify a hypercube of array indices, not each individually. Perhaps `i[3][5]` would suffice?

Comment: You can do it dynamically, but that involves an extra layer of indirection, more runtime, and a larger object. (_Ie_, what you proposed, `int *i[2]`.)

Comment: Thank you for teaching me union.
```
typedef struct{
        struct address{
                int row0[10], row1[5];
        } addr;
        int * map[2];
}registers;

registers new_reg() {
    registers r = { { {0}, {0} }, {r.addr.row0, r.addr.row1} };
    return r;
}
int main() {
    registers reg = new_reg();
    reg.map[0][0] = 5;
    printf("%d\n", reg.map[0][0]);
    return 0;
}


```

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple of issues.

You cannot have an initializer in a `struct` type definition; you must create an *instance* of the type and initialize members *in that instance*:

```
struct reg {
  struct address {
    int row0[10];
    int row1[5];
  } addr;
  int *i[2]; // we’ll talk about this later
};
...
struct reg r = // create an instance of struct reg
{
  {
    { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }, // row0
    { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 } // row1
  }, 
  { 
    r.addr.row0, r.addr.row1 // i
  }
};
```

Secondly, if you want `i` to be an actual *flexible array member* with no fixed size, then you have to dynamically allocate the object with enough extra space for the number of elements, otherwise it won’t be allocated in the object.  In other words, if your type definition is

```
struct reg {
  struct address {
    int row0[10];
    int row1[5];
  } addr;
  int *i[];
};
```

and you declare a variable as

```
struct reg r = { ... };
```

then the `i` member will not exist at all - if you try to add an initializer for the `i` member like I did above, the compiler will yell at you.

You would need to allocate an instance dynamically for the `i` member to exist, and only if you allocate extra memory for those array elements:

```
struct reg *r = malloc( sizeof *r + 2 * sizeof (int *) );
```

And then you would to assign members individually:

```
r->row0[0] = 0;
r->row0[1] = 1;
...
r->row1[0] = 0;
r->row1[1] = 1;
...
r->i[0] = r->row0;
r->i[1] = r->row1;
```

So after writing all of that, I saw your conversation with Neil; what you’re looking at is

```
union reg {
    struct address {
      int row0[10];
      int row1[5];
    } addr;
    int i[15];
};

union reg r = { .i = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, } };
```

or

```
union reg r = { 
  .addr = { 
    .row0 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
    .row1 = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 }
  }
};
```

either way should work.

Here's a dump of the memory map, showing the whole `union` object, then the `i` member, then the `addr` member, and then each of the `row0` and `row1` members - you can see that `r.i` and `r.addr` have the same size and starting address (which is the same as the starting address of the entire union object).  Similarly, `r.addr.row0` starts at that same address:

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
          r     0x16b0377b0   00   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377b4   01   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377b8   02   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377bc   03   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377c0   04   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377c4   05   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377c8   06   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377cc   07   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377d0   08   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377d4   09   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377d8   0a   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377dc   0b   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377e0   0c   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377e4   0d   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377e8   0e   00   00   00    ....

        r.i     0x16b0377b0   00   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377b4   01   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377b8   02   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377bc   03   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377c0   04   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377c4   05   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377c8   06   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377cc   07   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377d0   08   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377d4   09   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377d8   0a   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377dc   0b   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377e0   0c   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377e4   0d   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377e8   0e   00   00   00    ....

     r.addr     0x16b0377b0   00   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377b4   01   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377b8   02   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377bc   03   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377c0   04   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377c4   05   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377c8   06   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377cc   07   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377d0   08   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377d4   09   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377d8   0a   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377dc   0b   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377e0   0c   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377e4   0d   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377e8   0e   00   00   00    ....

r.addr.row0     0x16b0377b0   00   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377b4   01   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377b8   02   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377bc   03   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377c0   04   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377c4   05   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377c8   06   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377cc   07   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377d0   08   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377d4   09   00   00   00    ....

r.addr.row1     0x16b0377d8   0a   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377dc   0b   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377e0   0c   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377e4   0d   00   00   00    ....
                0x16b0377e8   0e   00   00   00    ....
```

Comment: Hi, John. Thanks for your response. could you finish your last line? what are u trying to do in the line " union reg r = { .row0 = ". How is it different from what Neil suggested? size was a problem there. did you overcome the size problem?

Comment: @Pragmatic: dammit, I thought I hit the "discard draft" button - I wasn’t intending to post that,  Ugh.  I will update that at some point, but it won’t be for a while.  Maybe this evening, I need to play with it to make sure I’m not lying to you.

Comment: No worries, I already have an solution that is working for me. which you can find in the body of my question. However, I am always trying improve my coding habits for best practices. If you have a better solution than what I currently have please post whenever you can. Thanks

Comment: @Pragmatic: See my edit - got a few minutes to make sure what I was writing would build and run as expected.